# Including JS files in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

How and where to put your own JS files in JQueryMobile web applications?

Some suggestions I found:

- only in the first page of the web app, usually index.html
- inside the JQM page

Which one is better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your jQuery Library and BEFORE your jQuery mobile library. I place all my script tags at the end of the body...but that's not a must...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuerySource.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
/*Your stuff*/
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="jQueryMobileSource.js">
```

Why?: Because when you're building your jQM application you're going to want your event bindings to be defined before jQuery mobile gets initialized and fires the 'mobileinit' event and your first page's 'pageinit' event.

Comment: only in index page all JQM pages?

Comment: Only on your original page, jQM, for the most part, reads the other page you're going to and inserts in into the DOM of your current page, then it fires pageinit on that page.  Give it a shot, although if you do it with Chrome locally it won't work.  Put it on a server or use on another browser to test, works great. That's the only exception I've found.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your script after the JQM script tag

Yeah, that's all

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to use jQueryMobile javascripts from Google CDNs because of following reasons:
1. You can directly include minified version in your pages. 
2. You save bandwidth cost
3. Most importantly there are good chances that the JS might already be loaded on your user browser's. Because many other web apps use them.
So you should use

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
```

So, if all your code is inside document.ready() ; you can use it at end [ which loads the page faster]

Comment: i mean on your own JS files, not the JQM js file.